# Escape a JavaScript string in Play 2.0 view?

Tags: playframework-2.0

Is there an easy way to escape a string to be used as a JavaScript string in a view in Play 2.0? For example, here's a simple view that creates a link with a confirm box in onclick:

```
@(text:String,link:Call,message:String)
<a href="@link" onclick="return confirm('@message');">@text</a>
```

That will fail if there are newlines or single quotes in message. What's the best way to do this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use Apache Commons Lang:

```html
@(text:String, link:Call, message:String)

@import org.apache.commons.lang3.StringEscapeUtils.escapeEcmaScript
<a href="@link" onclick="return confirm('@escapeEcmaScript(message)');">@text</a>
```

You can avoid the explicit import in the template by adding it to your `project/Build.scala` file:

```scala
templatesImport += "org.apache.commons.lang3.StringEscapeUtils.escapeEcmaScript"
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution. :) I am using Play 2.1 and default included library is `apache-commons-lang3`. I added `org.apache.commons.lang3.StringEscapeUtils.escapeEcmaScript` to `Build.scala` and used `escapeEcmaScript` in my templates instead of `escapeJavaScript`

Comment: Is it possible to combine this with `play`'s html escaping `@Html(message)` ? `@escapeEcmaScript(Html(message))` - doesn't work

Comment: This is not a good idea because it opens a XSS vulnerability. Why do need this?