# Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token in javascript with scala

Tags: javascript, scala, playframework

Can anyone check my code?
I don't know what happend but I got `Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token` at one of my templates.

```
<script type="text/javascript" nonce="templates-random-id">
@templates.map { t =>
    $('#template-@t.id').click(function() {
        document.getElementById('text').value = '@t.content';
    });
}</script>
```

I use it for loading a templates from database.

```
    @templates.map { t =>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" id="template-@t.id">@t.template_name</button>
}
```

What i got from the source in browser:

```
$('#template-17').click(function() {
            document.getElementById('text').value = 'blablabla blablablablablab lablablablabl ablablablablabla;';
        });
```

Edit: I will try change `'@t.content'` to `@t.content` with `.
Maybe it will help.

Answer (score 1):

This is probably because of `@t.content` which contains special symbols.
This fix might apply to your problem as well [Escape a JavaScript string in Play 2.0 view?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9743489/escape-a-javascript-string-in-play-2-0-view).

Comment: @Html(t.content) might help as well